Как запустить sh-файл при проходе по url
Есть файл, который расположен по адресу
/home/myUser/myFolder/myScript.sh

с правами:
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  root

Есть файл конфигурации nginx с поднятым сервисoм
server {
..
}

Ниже добисал блок:
server {
        listen myPort;
        server_name myDomain.ru;

        location /script_url {
            exec /home/myUser/myFolder/myScript.sh;
        }
}


Перезапустил сервис после внесенных изменений
sudo systemctl restart myService

Прохожу по ссылке:

http://myDomain.ru:myPort/script_url

Скрипт не запускается. Но если самому через консоль ввести
bash /home/myUser/myFolder/myScript.sh

То скрипт отрабатывает. Что я забыл сделать?

Nginx не умеет запускать скрипты.

@Alexey Ten, получается чтобы его запустить, я должен поднять мини приложение, которое будет запускать? Или может у ubuntu есть какой-то скрытый механихм?

Для nginx'а есть модуль perl напишите perl script или обертку на перле для вашего скрипта.

Наверное тебе вот это нужно: https://github.com/msoap/shell2http
